# Adjusting length of string when clicked: jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I **adjust the length of a string** when I've clicked on it?
Without complicating the entire code.

Something like strlen in php would be the solution.

See: // This

```
var toggleState = true;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.more').on("click", function() {
        if(toggleState) {
            $(this).length(unlimited characters); // This
        } else {
            $(this).length(100 characters); // This
        }
        toggleState = !toggleState;
    });
});
```

.length(unlimited characters) is just so that you understand what I mean/what I want to do. I need a solution, doesnt have to be length();

Comment: You can adjust the length by appending characters or removing characters.

Comment: `.length` is a property, not a method.

Comment: `'string'.length` would output 6. `'foo'.length` would output 3. If I wanted to adjust the length of those strings I would append additional characters or remove characters. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pYXVL/

Comment: Oh, actually - my mistake. I did not understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not try something like this, rather than relying on an arbitrary number of characters?

```
<div class="expandable">Blah blah blah blah... Lots of text here</div>
<a href="javascript:void(null);" class="expandlink">More...</a>
```

Then use this CSS:

```
.expandable {
    display: inline-block;
    width:90%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
.expandable.expanded {
    width:auto;
    display:block;
    white-space:normal;
}
```

And this jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".expandlink").click(function() {
        $(this.previousSibling.previousSibling).toggleClass("expanded");
        var t = $(this);
        t.text(t.text() == "More..." ? "Less..." : "More...");
    });
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/u3L34/) is a JSFiddle demonstrating this.

Comment: beautiful solution. Though, it should be noted that `text-overflow:ellipsis;` is CSS3, and not fully supported in some browsers.

Comment: IE6 supports it. I wouldn't worry too much. [Source:MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-overflow#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: spoke to soon. Seems to be pretty well supported indeed :)

Comment: Seems like the solution - But what if the width of the div the text was inside were 200px? Then the white-space: nowrap wouldn't work would it?

Comment: It should. I just used `90%` because it fit well with my screen width, it should be adjusted as needed.

Comment: It gets over the rest of my page :/

Comment: Did you forget the `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: Just one more thing, what if I want to show 2 rows instead of just one at start?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this with css. text-overflow:ellipsis and click.

http://jsfiddle.net/nhzDR/

#### HTML

```
<span class="clsshort">This is a very long text used to check how is everythign happening.This is a very long text used to check how is everythign happening.This is a very long text used to check how is everythign happening</span>
```

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.clsshort').on("click", function() {
       $(this).toggleClass("clsshort");
    });
});
```

#### CSS

```
span.clsshort
{
    width:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this basically my answer, just less user-friendly?

Comment: I dont think you can claim this as your answer. When i answer i don't look around many a times to see what others have written.. :) But Yes this was a quick write up... and yours is better.... Also this is too  generic and basic a solution to make a claim for... :)

Comment: Thanks for ur interest in helping @PSCoder I appreciate it. Great example :) If I had points I would vote you up but cant haha!

Comment: It is for a project which may lead to a full time job for me, so thanks that means alot

Comment: You dont happend to know how to make it show 2 rows instead of just 1 at start?